# launcher problem after installing the nvidia driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, launcher

I am using ubuntu 12.10 and unity as my desktop. recently I installed the nvidia driver using the package nvidia-current-updates but after that, when I move my mouse to the left side of the screen the launcher bar won't show up, what should I do??

Comment: If you have problem(s) with open source - nouveau, tell (post a comment) me to edit my answer

Comment: yes, nouveau driver don't have the functionality that I want. For example running a 3D game with wine will have low FPS but with the nvidia driver it will work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert back to open source nouveau (driver for nvidia). Why you installed nvidia additional driver ? Did you have any problem(s) with the nouveau ?

If you want to revert back execute below commands with order.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf #if file does not exit is OK# 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-common ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

and reboot your PC.

If you want the nvidia additional (restricted) drivers and the `nvidia-current` or `nvidia-current-updates` not working for you , then try the experimental ones.

**Nvidia-experimental-304 , terminal installation**

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-headers-generic 
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-source dkms
sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-304 nvidia-settings-experimental-304
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

and reboot your PC.

**Nvidia-experimental-310 terminal installation after nvidia-experimental-304 has been installed**

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-*
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo apt-get install nvidia-experimental-310 nvidia-settings-experimental-310
sudo nvidia-xconfig
```

**Before install any additional Nvidia driver** please see [here](http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) what graphic cards supported. Click upon the driver you want to install and then **supported products**.

Comment: typo at `reisntall`